# How to post data to a custom method using angular resource?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Dead simple scenario but it cant make it work.

I've got this resource

```
.factory('UserAccount',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('/useraccount/', {}, {
            set_password: {
                url: '/useraccount/set-password',
                method: 'POST',
            }
        });
    }
)
```

If i try to post data to `set_password` like thia  `user.$set_password({password:"secret"}, function ... )` it will just post the resource.

Is it even possible to pass custom data to a method (or do I need another resource... ) ?

angular 1.4.3, Thanks.

Comment: Without the $ should be good

Comment: Could you insert your controller code? Could you explain what is your problem exactly? What do you mean by "it will just post the resource"?

Comment: The code in the controller is simple , `user` is the example above is a `UserAccount` instance. If i do `user.$set_password({}, {password .. })` it's issuing a regular post request (with the entire `UserAccount` data).

Comment: Ok, instead of this `user.$set_password({password:"secret"}, function ... )` do this `user.set_password({password:"secret"}, function ... )`

Comment: There is no such function `set_password` the `$` sign indicate a resource method.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle to know how to use ngResource:

http://jsfiddle.net/thibaudsowa/7bhmq5he/

In your controller call your resource like this:

```
UserAccount.set_password({password:"secret"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```